# как результат метода с await присвоить в переменную?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, async-await, асинхронность

Есть в [документации](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-api-node#candles) для библиотеки `binance-api-node` вот такой пример:

```
console.log(await client.candles({ symbol: 'ETHBTC' }))
```

Должно вывести в консоль массив данных, но я получаю ошибку:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

или

```
Promise {<pending>}
```

Я использую react. Вот код:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Binance from 'binance-api-node';

const client = Binance();

export default class Exchange extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            symbol: 'COSBTC',
        };
    }

    async get_candles_list() {
        const candles_list = await client.candles({symbol: this.state.symbol, interval: '30m', limit: 10});
        return candles_list;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.get_candles_list())
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Как мне получить результат в переменную, чтобы потом передавать в другую библиотеку итп?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: С кодом всё ок. Проблема в вызове метода `client.candles(...`. Ошибка как раз об этом и сообщает: `Failed to fetch`

Comment: `componentDidMount() { console.log(` await `this.get_candles_list()) }`